# How to promote acorn maturation

Tags: botany, trees

I have acorns from an oak tree. They look like:
[image]

but I would like to speed up their maturation so they split and I can separate the caps:
[image]

How can I speed up this maturation process?

Comment: I am not sure but my instinct is to put them in a dry place with a lot of sun.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting them in the ground and watering them ([Factors affecting acorn production and germination and early growth of seedlings and seedling sprouts](https://www.nrs.fs.fed.us/pubs/other/oak_sym/oak_symposium_proceedings_044.pdf)).

Comment: Good idea, but in particular I'm not looking to grow a tree, rather to dismantle the acorn.

Comment: Sorry. Apparently I misunderstood you. It seems to me that you should leave them to dry (but that's just my feeling). Good luck...